# Generic Structures in C

Tags: c

Is there an option to create a generic structure, where providing a data type creates the corresponding structure?

For example:

```
typedef struct StbInt {
    int value;
    struct Stb *left;
    struct Stb *right;
} StbInt;
```

and

```
typedef struct StbChr {
    char value;
    struct Stb *left;
    struct Stb *right;
} StbChr;
```

Only the value variable has a different data type. Do I have to create two different structures?

Comment: I think you are looking for a `union`, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5842441/how-to-use-union-in-c-language

Comment: Note that the `struct Stb *` members in the structures shown are pointers to a type unrelated to the `struct StbInt` and `struct StbChr` types shown in the question.  Or, more plausibly, they're typos for `struct StbChr *` and `struct StbInt *`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to have some generality I would suggest using a `void*` data member, like this:

```
typedef  struct Stb{
    void*  value;
    size_t size_of_value;
    struct Stb *left;
    struct Stb *right;
}Stb;
```

That way you don't have to replicate code. You can see I added a data member named `size_of_value`, which should get the value of the data you are storing.

I would suggest you take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13224924/generic-binary-search-tree-in-c) question about **generic tree** in C.

---

"How can I point value to int or a char?" See the following two links:

[How do you convert void pointer to char pointer in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7067927/how-do-you-convert-void-pointer-to-char-pointer-in-c)

[How to cast an integer to void pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8487380/how-to-cast-an-integer-to-void-pointer)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `union` to do something like that:

```
typedef struct foo
{
  struct Stb *left;
  struct Stb *right;
  union bar
  {
    int intvalue;
    char *svalue;
  } bar;
} foo;
```

You may want another `struct` field determining what the type is.

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing I can think of to an abstract data-structure would be to fake it or to use a union.

In the case of faking it, chars can be looked at as really small ints so you could easily pack the char value into your int struct, or just use a void pointer.

```
typedef  struct StbVar {
    void *value;
    struct Stb *left;
    struct Stb *right;
};
```

As for a union you could union either the value or type it self. (In both cases you'll have to unpack the union to use the data.

```
// Union of types
union StbVar { 
    StbChr* c;
    StbChr* i;
};

// Union of values
typedef  struct StbVar {
    union {
        char character;
        int integer;
    };
    struct Stb *left;
    struct Stb *right;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

On this specific case, the two structure types are likely to have the same size because of padding after the `char` member. So instead of two different structure types, just use your `struct StbInt` for both uses, it will be more readable than to use useless `union` here.

Answer (score 0):

If your data is small (f.e. double, or int, or char), you can use `union`.

For large data you can use `void*` pointer on, and allocate a memory dynamically.

There is a little hack to simplify this method:

```
typedef struct UniversalNode {
    struct UniversalNode* left;
    struct UniversalNode* right;
    char data[1];
}
```

Then you can allocate memory to store two pointers and all necessary data:

```
UniversalNode* node = (UniversalNode*)malloc(2 * sizeof(void*) + DATA_SIZE);
Data* data = (Data*)&(node->data);
```

DATA_SIZE may be different for different nodes.

Comment: You could use a flexible array member (FAM) in C99 or later, instead of the old-style 'struct hack' you demonstrate.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, It's very difficult to give up old habits. :)